# What does x mean in the argument of this intertwiner?

Tags: representation-theory

[image: example 2.1.13]

I'm really confused as to what x is supposed to be here (I. E. In example 2.1.13, since the e_g is the element in k(G) that should be mapped to C(G) (which I'm presuming means the set of G to K functions?) This makes it impossible to understand how it could be injective. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I think you're right about $C(G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're getting confused between the function $\Phi:k(G) \to C(G)$ and the output $\Phi(\beta)$ (for a given $\beta \in k(G)$), which is itself a function from $G$ to $k$.   The fact which is being proven is that $\Phi$ is injective.  That is: given $\beta_1,\beta_2 \in k(G)$, the functions $\Phi(\beta_1),\Phi(\beta_2):G \to k$ will only be identical if $\beta_1 = \beta_2$.  The point is **not** to show that $\Phi(\beta)$ is an injective function.  In general, we should not expect $\Phi(\beta)$ to be injective.

In brief: we want to state that 
$$
\Phi(\beta_1)(x) = \Phi(\beta_2)(x) \quad \text{(for all $x \in G$)}\implies \beta_1 = \beta_2,
$$ not that $\Phi(\beta)(x_1) = \Phi(\beta)(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!